# TexStudio ignores makeindex parameters!

Tags: texstudio, imakeidx, makeindex

Nowadays I begin to use TexStudio in Windows. I can't understand one thing.

I want to stylish `\printindex`. So, I wrote, as usual, `_main.ist` file. After it I went to `Options` and make this: [image]

Then I `pdfLatex` my document. `Process exited normally`. But surprise is result of `\printindex` doesn't change.

And TexStudio writes to me.

> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit] (kpathsea +
>   Thai support). Scanning input file _main.idx....done (3 entries
>   accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries....done (4 comparisons).
>   Generating output file _main.ind....done (12 lines written, 0
>   warnings). Output written in _main.ind. Transcript written in
>   _main.ilg.

There is nothing about `_main.ist`. But if I make `Makeindex` command, without any `pdfLatex`, I see that TexStudio understands what I want:

> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning style file ./_main.ist.....done (5 attributes redefined, 0 ignored). Scanning input file _main.idx....done (3 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries....done (4 comparisons). Generating output file _main.ind....done (14 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in _main.ind. Transcript written in _main.ilg.

Do you see that it sees style file? It is great. And if I open `_main.idx` I see some beatiful `tikz`code. But `pdfLatex` calls `makeindex` without `-s` parameter and clears my beaty!

The question is how to teach TexStudio to make calling `pdfLatex` with correct command `makeindex` (with parameter `-s %.ist`)

Comment: you need to give makeindex the -s option before the main idx file so  presumably `makeindex -s %.ist %.idx`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry. It doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have texstudio so can't really help more, someone else will no doubt pass by:-)

Comment: If you name the style file `_main.mst` instead of `_main.ist`, then MakeIndex will use it without the need to pass the `-s` option. Unfortunately, TeXStudio hangs on my machine, so I can't help more.

Comment: Running `pdflatex` does not create the index printed in the output at all. It does not cause the entries in the `.idx` file to be scanned and it does not read the `.ist` file or write an `.ilg` file. So either TeXStudio is also running `makeindex` when you compile - and you are not just running `pdflatex` - or you have something in your document which causes the index to be created as part of the compilation with `pdflatex`, but you've not provided an MWE so we cannot know what that might be. Presumably you are using `imakeidx`, judging by the tag. What's the code?

Comment: @cfr Oh. Great! before asking this question my opinion was the same as yours. Well, it means that TexStudio misleads me. I have a big book. Suddenly I understood that index is missing! So, I added `\usepackage{imakeidx}`,
`\indexsetup{level=\chapter,toclevel=chapter}`,
`\makeindex` in the preambule before loading `hyperref`. And I inserted `\printindex` where I want to get it. Also, I gave system `.ist` file. As I said,te book is huge, so it can't be MWE. But after your comment I will play with files and maybe will create MWE.

Comment: Yes, so TeXStudio is not running `makeindex`. When it does, it uses the options. The output you are seeing is from `imakeidx` integrating the creation of the index. If you want to change the output, you have to change what `imakeidx` does.